# Why was Chiwetel Ejiofor made to be part Indian in The Martian?

Tags: character, the-martian

Why was Chiwetel Ejiofor's character made out to be part Indian (Vincent Kapoor) in the movie The Martian? He otherwise has no Indian history, looks to be Nigerian. Was there a reason why the creators went out of the way to establish Chiwetel Ejiofor's character to have a part Indian origin? It didn't seem relevant to the plot otherwise.

Comment: According to the Trivia page on IMDB, Irrfan Khan was originally cast as Vincent Kapoor. [IMDB Trivia - Vincent Kapoor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3659388/trivia?item=tr2568035) This would have been consistent with the book, in which Venket Kapoor was Indian. There are other sources corroborating the story. Irrfan Khan was simply overbooked with other movies (Piku and Jurrasic World). [India Today](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/irrfan-khan-chose-piku-over-ridley-scotts-the-martian-jurrasic-world/1/432584.html) [Bollywood Hungama](http://www.bollywoodhungama.com/movies/features/type/view/

Answer (score 10):

The movie character, Vincent Kapoor, was originally **Venket Kapoor, and fully Indian** in the book of the same name. The casting of Chiwetel Ejiofor required a slight change on background of the character, otherwise keeping the history intact.

Ridley Scott has not answered any questions on why the casting and changes were made, even when criticized for "white-washing".